# Sorting with Angular Js cause to jump on top of page

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

below is my HTML Table

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-sm ">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>
                <a href="#" ng-click="sortType ='Product';sortReverse =!sortReverse">Product</a>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'Product' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'Product' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'Location';sortReverse =!sortReverse">Location</a>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'Location' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'Location' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'Qty';sortReverse =!sortReverse">Qty.</a>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'Qty' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'Qty' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = 'UnitPrice';sortReverse =!sortReverse">UnitPrice</a>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'UnitPrice' && !sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'UnitPrice' && sortReverse" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in ProductInfo | orderBy :sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchText" ng-class="$even?'table-danger':'table-info'">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Product}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Location}}</td>
            <td>{{x.Qty}}</td>
            <td>{{x.UnitPrice | currency : '&#x20B9;':2}}</td>
            <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true" style="color:red"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And Angular Js code is

```
$scope.ProductInfo=[
    {Product:"CRX-MB100",Location:"Org-W40",Qty:"200",UnitPrice:"1000"},

    {Product:"MVP-Q100",Location:"Org-D800",Qty:"500",UnitPrice:"2500"},

    {Product:"EMP-QX100Z",Location:"Org-US09",Qty:"400",UnitPrice:"1800"},

    {Product:"RT23-QXP888M",Location:"Org-Dist09",Qty:"100",UnitPrice:"2500"},

    {Product:"ZyF-AMD300",Location:"Org-W50",Qty:"200",UnitPrice:"1200"},
    ]

    $scope.sortType     = 'Product'; // set the default sort type
    $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
    $scope.searchText   = '';     // set the default search/filter
```

That's working perfectly , clicking on table header sort the table but also jump on Top of the page which is problematic cause have to scroll down again to table to see the resultant data , A single page application should not flicker (specially with Angular js like heroic platform).

I searched a lot for this behaviour but did not get anything , help is appreciable to know this behaviour and prevent it.

Code is referenced from  https://scotch.io/tutorials/sort-and-filter-a-table-using-angular

Comment: Because `href="#"` You can replace that with `href=""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `href="#"` You can replace that with `href=""`

Show the code here :
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NaBxZm

Comment: Thanks , that was a small thing